# Wufoo image upload issue

Tags: wufoo

If anyone can help me with this or confirm this issue it would be very appreciated.

I'm running into issues where in wufoo is adding .png to all images submitted through my form. So instead of picture.jpg I get picture.jpg.png. Does anyone know of any workarounds for this?